# Controlling date formatting on .NET WCF service request

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I'm trying to call a web service from .NET 3.5 using WCF. The error I'm getting currently is

> An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.
>
> InnerException: {"Value -2147483648 for millisOfSecond must be in the range [0,999]"}

I've narrowed it down to two date values I'm sending. When I create the request through soapUI, and send the date values in this format:

> 2010-07-19T00:00:00.000Z

everything works fine, but when I call the service from .NET, it sends the dates in this format

> 2010-07-19T00:00:00

and it results in the error above. If I send the incorrect date in soapUI, I get the same error message. Note that these dates are required fields, so if I send nothing it puts a default date of 0001-01-01T00:00:00 in, which is still obviously in the wrong format.

How can I control how the date is sent to the web service?

Comment: I gather is a non-WCF web service. Can you post the wsdl or xsd of the operation/datatype in question. I am curious to see.

Comment: The wsdl is quite large, but the element is defined as <element name="fromDate" type="dateTime" />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if there's an easier way for this (haven't found it, yet, if it exists) - but one method of doing this would be to introduce a string field that properly formats your date, and then avoid serializing the date field directly, but instead serialize the formatted string:

```
public partial class YourDataClass
{

    public DateTime YourDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="YourDate")]
    public string FormattedDate
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ}", YourDate);
        set { ; }
    }
}
```

With this, the `DateTime` field `YourDate` won't be serialized (no `[DataMember]` attribute on it - assuming you're using the DataContract serializer in WCF), while the formatted date string will be serialized as `YourDate` in the proper format.